# How to read standard barcodes (EAN) with zxing? iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode, zxing

Hi folks just a quick question, how do I read non-QR codes with zxing? I am setting the ZXingWidgetController to 1D mode, and am using a MultiFormatUPCEANReader however the barcodes just won't scan. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their site, only QR was ported to iPhone.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

> iphone: iPhone client + port to Objective C / C++ (QR code only)

Answer (score 7):

However, someone did it: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Answer (score 2):

As Lou says, zxing only support QR codes on iPhone.

A better bet is to use the alternative library ZBar, which supports EAN/UPC and is available here:

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html

Comment: What don't you like about the license?

Comment: Please Refer to the following document. ESPECIALLY THIS PART 2.6.3. Object File Distribution http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/licensing.html